# NestJS typeORM fails on Production while works fine locally

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm running a NestJS server with a Postgres database. The NestJS server works fine  locally, but in production, it always results in the following error:

```
[Nest] 20  - 09/05/2023, 8:43:09 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cyclic dependency: "d"
TypeORMError: Cyclic dependency: "d"
at visit (/app/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectTopoligicalSorter.js:147:23)
at visit (/app/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectTopoligicalSorter.js:164:21)
at SubjectTopoligicalSorter.toposort (/app/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectTopoligicalSorter.js:143:17)
at SubjectTopoligicalSorter.sort (/app/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectTopoligicalSorter.js:53:45)
at SubjectExecutor.execute (/app/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectExecutor.js:91:108)
at EntityPersistExecutor.execute (/app/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/EntityPersistExecutor.js:140:36)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

I connected my local development server to my remote production Postgres database, and it works fine. Only when my production server connects to the production Postgres database - then I get the error above.

My server is a NestJS server running with the following stack:

```
Node: 16.19.1
Package Manager: npm 8.19.3
OS: darwin arm64

"dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^13.0.0",
        "@angular/cdk": "^13.0.0",
        "@angular/common": "^13.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^13.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "^13.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^13.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "^13.0.0",
        "@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0",
        "@nestjs/config": "^3.0.0",
        "@nestjs/core": "^8.0.0",
        "@nestjs/jwt": "^10.0.3",
        "@nestjs/mapped-types": "^2.0.2",
        "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.0.0",
        "@nestjs/serve-static": "^4.0.0",
        "@nestjs/typeorm": "^10.0.0",
        "@nrwl/angular": "13.3.1",
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
        "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
        "class-validator": "^0.14.0",
        "cloudinary": "^1.37.3",
        "express": "^4.18.2",
        "http-status-codes": "^2.2.0",
        "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
        "pg": "^8.11.1",
        "primeflex": "^3.3.0",
        "primeicons": "^4.1.0",
        "primeng": "^13.4.1",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
        "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
        "sqlite3": "^5.1.6",
        "tslib": "^2.0.0",
        "typeorm": "^0.3.17",
        "uuid": "^9.0.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
    },

"devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.0.0",
        "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~13.0.1",
        "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~13.0.1",
        "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~13.0.1",
        "@angular/cli": "^13.3.4",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.0.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "^13.0.0",
        "@nestjs/schematics": "^8.0.0",
        "@nestjs/testing": "^8.0.0",
        "@nrwl/cli": "13.3.1",
        "@nrwl/cypress": "13.3.1",
        "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "13.3.1",
        "@nrwl/jest": "13.3.1",
        "@nrwl/linter": "13.3.1",
        "@nrwl/nest": "13.3.1",
        "@nrwl/node": "13.3.1",
        "@nrwl/tao": "13.3.1",
        "@nrwl/workspace": "13.3.1",
        "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
        "@types/jest": "27.0.2",
        "@types/multer": "^1.4.7",
        "@types/node": "^15.14.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~5.3.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "~5.3.0",
        "cypress": "^8.3.0",
        "eslint": "8.2.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.10.3",
        "jest": "27.2.3",
        "jest-preset-angular": "11.0.0",
        "prettier": "^2.3.1",
        "ts-jest": "27.0.5",
        "typescript": "~4.4.3"
    }
```

And I have the following entities:

```
@Entity()
export class PatientEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @Column({ type: 'date' })
    dateOfBirth: Date;

    @Column({ unique: true })
    email: string;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    phoneNumber: string;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    photo: string | null;

    @OneToMany(
        () => MedicalPlanEntity,
        plan => plan.patient,
        { cascade: true }
    )
    plans: MedicalPlanEntity[];
}
```

and

```
@Entity()
export class MedicalPlanEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    name: string;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    description: string;

    @ManyToOne(
        () => PatientEntity,
        patient => patient.plans,
        { nullable: true }
    )
    patient: PatientEntity;
}
```

and my orm.config file is as follows:

```
import { registerAs } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

export default registerAs(
    'orm.config',
    (): TypeOrmModuleOptions => ({
        ssl: true,

        extra: {
            ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }
        },
        type: 'postgres',
        autoLoadEntities: true,
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        port: Number(process.env.DB_PORT),
        username: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    })
);
```

Any idea why in production I have the error above, while it works fine locally?

Answer (score 0):

After spending some days on this, it appeared that there were incompatibility issues between NestJS 8 and TypeOrm in production mode.

The letter `d` in the strange and untraceable error I was getting: `TypeORMError: Cyclic dependency: "d"` - was a minified reference of one of my entities, that only appeared in production because the code is minified and optimized only in production.

To solve this, you have to upgrade to the most recent stack of nestjs and typeORM, or

**only as a workaround**, you can turn optimization to `false` in production, and the error will go away:

```
"configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "optimization": false, // <--- false
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "inspect": false,
                            // ...
                            ]
                        }
                    }
```